# How we can iterate cards combinations efficiently?

Tags: c, algorithm, bitmap, bit-manipulation, poker

There is a huge number of poker hands possible. We would like to decrease this by removing the similar hands so that we can iterate through each individual possible combination.

In order to do so, the possible combinations are denoted by strings of length 52 where a '0' signifies that the card is not present and a '1' signifies that the card is present.

So hands of 
2,3,4,5,6 of hearts will be:  '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111'

2,4,10,A of hearts and 3 of clubs will be :
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000101000100000101'

and so on...

Here first 13 bits signify A,K,Q,...4,3,2 of spades,
Next 13 bits are for diamonds
next 13 for clubs
and last 13 for hearts

Now what we need to do is, from the decimal value of a binary string, reduce it to a similar poker hand's binary string and return its decimal value

So what do I mean when I say similar hands:-
 - A,Q,7,6,2 of spades = AQ762 of clubs = AQ762 of hearts = AQ762 of diamonds
so each of their binary representation can be reduced to the binary representation of AQ762 of hearts, which is the smallest
 - Similarly, a hand of 2,3,4,5 of spades and A of diamonds is equivalent to A of hearts and 2,3,4,5 of clubs, so the former can be reduced to the latter.

```
AsKsQsJsTs = 1111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
AcKcQcJcTc = 0000000000000000000000000011111000000000000000000000
AdKdQdJdTd = 0000000000000111110000000000000000000000000000000000
AhKhQhJhTh = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000001111100000000

Ac5s4s3s2s = 0000000001111000000000000010000000000000000000000000
Ah5c4c3c2c = 0000000000000000000000000000000000011111000000000000
Ac5d4d3d2d = 0000000000000000000000111100000000000001000000000000
```

But I know:

```
AKQJTs == AKQJTc == AKQJTd == ... are same, because combination have same strength in poker, we can simplify suits
Ac5432s == Ah5432c == Ah5432d == ... are same
```

I think we can use abstraction for suits: [1], [2], [3], [4]

```
[1] - new first suit, suit of highest card
[2] - second suit if we are going down from highest card


65432[1] == 65432s == 65432c == 65432d == ..
6[1]5432[2] == 6c5432s == 6h5432c == 6c5432d == ..
```

The first suit of highest card is [1] and next new suit [2]....

And masks will be:

```
AKQJTs=AKQJTc=AKQJTd=AKQJTh = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000001111100000000 = 7936

Ah5432c=Ac5432d= ... = 0000000000000000000000000000000000011111000000000000 = 126976
```

**How I can make this mask conversion efficiently?**

Like - `simplyfyMask(4362862139015168) = 7936`
`simplyfyMask(1040187392) = 126976`

*PS: if I will use another mask: Aces - 0,1,2,3, Kings - 4,5,6,7, Jacks - 8,9,10,11 - bits?*

Comment: Sorry but ... what? oO I guess this needs some explanation.

Comment: I can but what I need add. I think this is interesting task and I do not how to solve

Comment: It will be very helpful if more information is provided. Like expected outcomes based on inputs. And please explain abbreviations like `AsKsQsJsTs`

Comment: Suits: clubs (♣), diamonds (♦), hearts (♥) and spades (♠)

Comment: Well, it's possible to figure out these abbreviations (but yes, **explain** them explicitly, like *Ace of spades*). What's entirely unclear is the rules by which you state "*these are the same*". What's "*the same*"?

Comment: Ranks: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T(10), J(Jack), Q(Queen), K(King), A(Ace). 52 cards in deck

Comment: And then, if you always have a set of five cards, why not just define `uint8_t` constants for every card (values 0 to 51) and have an array of 5 `uint8_t`to represent them? Would only take 40 bits this way and is probably easier to handle.

Comment: @IlyaKey don't explain anything in comments, **edit your question** in a way so it's comprehensible to readers.

Comment: @FelixPalmen sorry - editing...

Comment: What is `6[1]5432[2]` ?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya [1] - new first suit, suit of highest card
[2] - second suit if we are going down from highest card..

Comment: I think you want a poker-hand-evaluator. I spent some time with this topic and I think this is the best you can get: http://suffe.cool/poker/evaluator.html

Comment: @Selindek I have realized evaluator, I need make amount of combinations smaller...

Comment: Why would you use a bitset, and not an ordered sequence... With ordered sequence you just need 6 bits per card, times 5 for 30 which will fit in a long int. You cannot hold the **whole deck** in hand.

Comment: what does "decimal" mean when you use it?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala because I need hold in hand 5-7 cards.

Comment: In the article I linked there is a very well described algorithm how can you convert ANY of the 2,598,960 possible unique poker hands into one of the 7462 possible distinct values of poker hands. (In the fastest way)

Comment: @Selindek nice! I will read it

Comment: You might check out my onejoker library on Github...it contains an iterator class specifically for fast enumeration of combinations of cards

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided:
*simplyfyMask(1040187392) = 126976*
You can furthur reduce this:

from -*0000000000000000000000000000000000011111000000000000*

to - - -*0000000000000000000000000000000000000011000000001110*

As they have equal ranks as a poker hand

Here is a python code for this (Hope this helps, I am not a C programmer, so didn't answer in C language)

```
def replaceByindex(string, index, value) :
    li = list(string)
    li[index] = value
    return ''.join(li)

def checkFlush(string) :
    for suit in range(4) :
        count = 0
        # print(suit,'-th suit check for flush')
        for card in range(13) :
            if string[suit*13 + card] != '0' :
                count += 1
        if count == 0 :
            continue
        elif count == 5 :
            # print('Flushed')
            return True
        else :
            # print(count,'cards counted for',suit,'-th suit')
            return False

def unFlushify(string) :
    if checkFlush(string) :
        for card in range(13) :
            index = 51 - card
            if string[index] == '2' :
                string = replaceByindex(string,index-13,'2')
                string = replaceByindex(string,index,'0')
                break
    return string

def  simplifyMask(num) :
    num = bin(num)
    num = num[2:]
    size = len(num)
    num = '0'*(52-size) + num
    # print(num, len(num))
    count = 0
    i = 0
    if not checkFlush(num) :
        while i<52 and count<5 :
            if num[i] == '1' :
                count += 1
                tgt_index = 39 + i%13
                updated = False
                while tgt_index>i and num[tgt_index] != '0' :
                    tgt_index -=13
                if tgt_index <= i :
                    num = replaceByindex(num,i,'2')
                else :
                    num = replaceByindex(num,i,'0')
                    num = replaceByindex(num,tgt_index,'2')
            i+=1
        num = unFlushify(num)
    else :
        while i<52 and count<5 :
            if num[i] == '1' :
                count+=1
                num = replaceByindex(num,i,'0')
                num = replaceByindex(num,39+i%13,'2')
    return num.replace('2','1')


num = int(input())
number = simplifyMask(num)
print(int(number,2),number)
```

I consider myself a beginner in coding, so this might not be the most efficient piece of code, but this should give you the idea of how to proceed. :)